# Nickname always null in discord command

Tags: php, discord

I want to reply to a user that has typed a slash command. I would like to use his nickname if he has one, but it's always null.
My code (a PHP function for a command) :

```
private function commandWho(Interaction $interaction) {
    $name = $interaction->member->user->username;
    echo "\nName :\n";
    echo $name;
    echo "\nNickname :\n";
    echo $interaction->member->nick;
    echo "\nEnd\n";
```

Example with the user "ChumGum" who has the nickname "Bao". It returns :

```
Name :
ChumGum
Nickname :

End
```

How do you have the nickname loaded ?

Comment: Do you have members intent enabled? If I'm remember correctly, you can't get any data about members if you not enabled this feature in the both bot's settings on developers portal and on bot initialization in code.

Comment: I'm not sure tu understand your question (I'm new with Discord), but in the developper portal, in OAuth2, I checked "bot" and "applications.commands", and in Bot, I checked "Administrator". Is that what you mean ?

Comment: I don't see "members intent" in these lists, so I bet it's not the place you're talking about.

Comment: Im talking about [these intents](https://i.imgur.com/RTavLKD.png).

Comment: Both cursors are on for my bot.

Comment: As it is a command, I read the member in $interaction. But perhaps should I take it from the discord object (I store it in $this->discord in the constructor). What would be the path to find it ? I already tried some with no success.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Maybe your library just not resolving something correctly. I don't used PHP library for the Discord so I don't know exactly how to possibly resolve this.